# Unable to establish JDBC connection to Oracle DBMS in Eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, jdbc, connection

I'm using Oracle 18c Express edition and trying to connect to the same using the below code.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin://@localhost:1521/XE", "system", "Root123");
```

And upon execution, there's an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
```

I am unable to figure out what's wrong with the URL.
Kindly help resolve this issue.
TIA.

Comment: Should `/XE` be `:XE`, instead?

Comment: Tried. Even that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) the URL should be:

```
jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<user>/<password>@<database>
```

Where user and password can be provided as connection properties:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");
```

You probably need to remove the `//` from the URL as well:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```